# How can I compute the number of solutions to an under-constrained equation over some integers?

Tags: linear-algebra, integer-lattices, mixed-integer-programming, linear-diophantine-equations

I have system of under-constrained equations over a fixed set of integers, defined as follows, how can I find the number of solutions to this problem? A computational reference will do (in-fact preferred).

$\alpha_{ij} \in \{0,1,2,3,4\}$.
$i$ goes from $1$ to $5$
and $j$ goes from $1$ to $4$

the constraint is given as follows:
$$\frac{\sum_{i,j}\alpha_{ij}}{2} = 10$$
$$\sum_j\alpha_{ij} = 4$$

Comment: Note that your two constraints are not independent. In fact if $\forall i,\sum_j \alpha_{i,j}=4$ then the other is automatically $4\times 5=20$. So you just need to satisfy the second one.

Comment: That solves it thanks alot !